# Word document has very strange "hidden" formating after converting from PDF to .docx

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a PDF document with my resume which I need to edit. I used [this service](http://www.pdftoword.com/) to convert it to doc. I opened it in Word 2010 and saved it as .docx. There are some bizzare problems where there's empty space and if you try to delete it text gets shifted into vertical columns. How can I fix this? I'm afraid this document has a lot of private information and I can't just fill in dummy text, then the formatting gets even more messed up :/ Otherwise I'd post screen shots.

Comment: It sounds like the service you are using is the reason the hidden formating characters exist in the document I would try a better service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have luck copying and pasting chunks of content one at a time to a new document. Even if this doesn't work you may find the root cause of whats causing the strange formatting.